# The time derivative of $ \|P(t)\|_{F}^{2} + \|\hat{x}(t)\|^2 $ is not well defined ?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, tensor-products

$\|.\|_{F}$ denotes the matrix frobenius norm. Both $P \in \mathbb{R}^{N X N} $ and $\hat{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{N}$ are functions of time. When I evaluate the derivative with respect to time , $\dfrac{\partial\|P\|_{F}^{2}}{\partial t} \in \mathbb{R}^{NXN}$ whereas $\dfrac{\partial \|\hat x\|^2}{\partial t} \in \mathbb{R}$ which means they can no longer be added directly !  I realize that matrix derivatives don't follow the chain rule, but since both functions output a scalar and the independent variable is a scalar too, I feel there should be a way to solve this. Am I missing something fundamental here ? Does this have anything to do with Tensors ?

A Little background : I am trying to evaluate the gradient of a optimization cost on the covariance matrix $P$ and on the state estimate $\hat{x}$. (I have ignored the integral in the question for simplicity).

Answer (score 2):

Both $\|P(t)\|_F^2$ and $\|\hat{x}(t)\|^2$ are maps from $\Bbb{R}$ to $[0,\infty)$, so the derivative of each will also be a scalar.  Recheck your derivation for $\partial_t \|P\|_F^2$.

Comment: $\partial_{t} \|P\|_{F}^{2} = \dfrac{\partial \|P\|_{F}^{2}}{\partial P} * \partial_{t} P = 2P *\partial_{t} P $ . Both of these terms belong to $ \mathbb {R}^{NXN}$ right ? So wont the result also be a $N X N $ matrix ?

Comment: Well, almost - that $*$ should be taken to mean Frobenius inner product, which multiplies the matrices _pointwise_ then _sums_ the result.  Essentially the Frobenius norm treats $P$ like a vector.  Another way to see this is to just write out the sum for $\|P\|_F^2$ and differentiate it term-by-term.